# Is there a single standard tool for creating a reverse feed for blog posts?

Tags: blog, rss, feeds

I'd like to create a custom "reverse" RSS feed that periodically releases old blog posts in reverse order.  Alternatively, I'd like to create a feed that allows someone to read through the archives of the blog from the beginning.  Is there a single standard tool for doing this?

(Edited to try and comply with the moderation.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question is too broad and will primarily result in either answers regarding how to code this (though it's not clear what language, framework, or stack you're using), or possibly recommendations for software, both of which are considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) here. If you can provide some more details with code you've tried, you could ask this over at Stack Overflow. For software recommendations, you could try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their FAQ first.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all that a good answer would be long.  Seems like the kind of thing you can only learn after the question is asked.  Indeed, the worry seems to be that there is no standard tool (so requiring a long answer) or that there are too many tools (requiring opinion/debate).  What if there's one standard tool?  How would I find that out?  I get the point of the heavy moderation on SE sites, really I do, but it seems to me that there are at least 3 SEs sites that I could submit this question to and they would *all* reject it because I don't know enough to tailor it to them.

Comment: On hold reasons are pretty limited and pre-written, which is why I tried to explain why this would be considered off-topic here. Unfortunately not all questions are a good fit for SE sites. Questions seeking recommendations for tools or software are generally considered off-topic for all SE sites since they often result in spam and promotional answers. [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) was proposed for that reason - I'd suggest that site if you're looking for a tool, but be sure to check the Help Center there first to avoid possible further rejections.

Comment: I wasn't responding to the pre-written on-hold message, I was responding to your comment (which I appreciate you took the time to write).  Here by "tool" I meant anything like "the designated parameter in an RSS feed" or "the industry standard piece of open source software that everyone uses".  I specifically edited the question so that the answer could simply be "no, there is no single standard tool" which would be *very useful* to someone else searching Google for this information.

Comment: It's very doubtful that users would only answer "no", nor does this question preclude something other than a "yes" or "no" answer. Most likely users would answer with what they though was a "standard" tool, which would be considered either opinion-based or a [recommendation for a tool](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), both of which are off-topic here for the above reasons. Feel free to ask this in our Chat room however, where either is fine. Good luck.

Comment: That class of criticism ("the question is OK but users are likely to give bad and distracting answers") could be used to close off just about any question. I suspect the real reason is just "the question is too basic", which is fine but which I'd rather that were made explicit.

Comment: It was put on hold because it was too broad previously, and then edited to ask for a "standard" tool, which would lead to opinion-based answers and recommendations, which are off-topic for all SE sites except Software Recommendations. So no, the question was not OK by the standards of this site as to what's considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Again, you can ask this in our Chat room, or possibly [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).